Is it possible to use an indeclinable noun locatively?
Classical names of cities and towns can be declined in the locative forms, and it seems this can be applied to later names. However, many post-Classical city names are too foreign to have a form latinized enough, and so they become indeclinable.
Is there any attestable practice to use the locative form, which is morphologically same as the nominative form, of such names? I wonder if there are any cases of Hebrew names found in Christian texts but I don't know how to search.

Regarding Biblical usage, I think (but don't know for sure) you never, ever see the locative of indeclinable names. For example, it seems to always be in Jerusalem, whereas for the declinable Jerosolyma (same town, of course) you do see the locative, which for whatever reason is Jerosolymis. You also find the plain accusative of direction. e.g. reversus est Jerusalem, but also, of course, venite, venite in Bethlehem (OK, that's not the Bible, but see e.g. Mt. 2:8).

@SebastianKoppehel What's your advice for handling such names? I remember I have read a random book on botanical Latin, where the author suggests that indeclinable place names should be used with an appositive common noun in order to make its grammatical role clear.

Intellego, ut obiter dicam, te Sinensem esse; si res ita se habet, fortasse hoc index Sinarum Imperii urbium praecipuarum, saeculo XVII a quodam Helevetico conscriptum, te delectabit. Sanghaevum autem, maxima hodie Sinarum metropolin, frustra quaeres.

Before delving into the question of how to deal with undeclinable names, first a bit of a "frame challenge": Having a Latin form is generally the better option – or at least the Latin text will flow best and feel most natural that way – and it may not be as unfeasible as you think:

Find out if really nobody has given the place in question a Latin name yet. Karl Egger's Lexicon Nominum Locorum is a good place to look for existing Latinizations.

If there is no Latin name yet: Dare to Latinize ;-) This is frequently done and is often as easy as adding an -um to the local name. For example, my native town is locally called "Hamburg" – as un-Latin-sounding as you could wish for – and the established Latinization has long been to simply call it Hamburgum. If the name ends in -o, it seems to be common to replace it with -um; e.g. Sapporo → Sapporum; if the name happens to end in -a, well, you're done already. It is also common to adapt the spelling to remove certain sounds that are foreign to Latin (sh in particular) as well as the letter W, for understandable reasons; so for example, Schwechat becomes Svecatum (oppidum Vindobonae conterminatum, as Egger remarks, although it is more well known as the name of the Viennese airport nowadays).


Having said all that, if you are dealing with an indeclinable name, I believe the common practice is to not use the locative, but in + name. As I wrote in a comment, the Vulgate Bible, which largely refrains from declining Hebrew names, gives many examples for this usage. To give you a taste of what that looks like, see this entry for Jerusalem in a Latin Bible concordance. I would personally be somewhat wary of using the plain accusative of direction, and might prefer in + name for this as well (as in Matth. 2:8, mittens illos in Bethlehem), although to tell the truth, the Biblical text often uses the plain accusative.
You also mention the suggestion that "indeclinable place names should be used with an appositive common noun in order to make its grammatical role clear." I believe this is a good idea. (Technically, since words like oppidum, urbs, civitas, etc. do not have a locative, this means that you will use the ablative of your indeclinable name, although it obviously makes no visible difference.) This is also helpful when readers will not be familiar with the name and may not even realize it is a settlement at first.  In that case it will be helpful to say, e.g., quod narrabo factum est cum in oppido XY habitabam &c.
It is worth mentioning that there is also Biblical precedent for this, e.g. Matth. 2:23 Habitavit in civitate quae vocatur Nazareth … id. 4:13 et, relicta civitate Nazareth, venit &c.
As a matter of style, though, I would not repeat this every time the place is mentioned in the text. Eventually the reader will have understood what kind of place is designated by the name, and it will appear tiresome to repeat it every time.
